# how to generate entities and schemas for enum in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

i am trying to generate entities for my contact information. for that i have first create Entity with the following syntax used where i have created one enum field.

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="BannerTestBundle.contact" --fields="name:string(255) lastname:string(255) phone:integer(10) gender:enum("male","female") message:text".
```

The above command generate the entity class but when i am trying to generate "entities" from the class it will show error the command is.

```
 php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Banner/TestBundle/Entity/contact
```

it will show the following error.

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant male, property Banner\TestBundle\
Entity\contact::$gender.

doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

i want to generate database with following fields:

```
Contact.table
Name-string(255)
LastName-string(255)
Phone:integer(10)
gender:enum("male","female")
message:text
```

please help into it as i am new in symfony

Here is Contact Entity file

```
 <?php

  namespace Banner\TestBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

  /**
 * contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Banner\TestBundle\Entity\contactRepository")
 */
 class contact
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $lastname;

/**
 * @var enum
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="enum", length=male,female)
 */
private $gender;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="integer", length=12)
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text")
 */
private $message;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return contact
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set lastname
 *
 * @param string $lastname
 * @return contact
 */
public function setLastname($lastname)
{
    $this->lastname = $lastname;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lastname
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLastname()
{
    return $this->lastname;
}

/**
 * Set gender
 *
 * @param \enum $gender
 * @return contact
 */
public function setGender(\enum $gender)
{
    $this->gender = $gender;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get gender
 *
 * @return \enum 
 */
public function getGender()
{
    return $this->gender;
}

/**
 * Set phone
 *
 * @param integer $phone
 * @return contact
 */
public function setPhone($phone)
{
    $this->phone = $phone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phone
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPhone()
{
    return $this->phone;
}

/**
 * Set message
 *
 * @param string $message
 * @return contact
 */
public function setMessage($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get message
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getMessage()
{
    return $this->message;
}
}
```

Comment: Show us the part of your Entity with the annotations from $gender.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your annotation is not in the right format.
Try this :

```
@ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", columnDefinition="enum('male', 'femelle')")
```

And do not forget to add

```
mapping_types:
    enum: string
```

below

```
doctrine:
     dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
```

in the `app/config/config.yml` file.

More information about enum in doctrine [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html).

Comment: After changing according to your suggestion it's shows following error.                                                                 

      [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
      Class "Banner\TestBundle\Entity\Contact" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
    doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name

Comment: Try to remove length from the phone annotations. You cant specify a length to an integer

Comment: Done i have make changes in anotation file and it's working fine now. Thanks for help

Comment: You can also map to 'varchar' per the docs.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/mysql-enums.html  I have no idea which is better.

Comment: Thanks man. This was a life saver at 4:33 am in the morning :)